# Sort listview via complex item

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` of items. The items contain alpha-numeric characters. I would like to sort them by the numbers in the strings.

for example:

player 5:51

player 2:45

player 1:40

Comment: Write your own [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)

Comment: Can you post the code? I have a hunch that you might want to use a Comparator
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html
You can create a class like class myItem {string name, int number} and then create an array like so myitem[] , then execute this sort method on this array:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[], java.util.Comparator<? super T>)
Does this work?

Comment: i have tried some ways to sort the array who set to list view but finally i couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as what i understood from your question i think you need to use `Collections.sort()`

so:

```
if(!empNames.isEmpty()){

    for(String item:yourList){

        System.out.println(item);
    }

    Collections.sort(yourList);

    System.out.println(yourList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Write your own Comparator
- Sort the array "collection" .. important to do that before fetching the listview
- fetch the listview with the sorted collection